# I believe [dcl.typedef]/1 has a defect, otherwise what am I missing?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, typedef

[[decl.pre]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#10):

> If the *decl-specifier-seq* contains the `typedef` specifier, the
> declaration is called a *typedef declaration* and each *declarator-id*
> is declared to be a *typedef-name*, synonymous with its associated
> type ([dcl.typedef]).
>
> [Note 4: Such a *declarator-id* is an *identifier* ([class.conv.fct]).
> — end note]
>
> If the *decl-specifier-seq* contains no `typedef` specifier, the
> declaration is called a *function declaration* if the type associated
> with a *declarator-id* is a function type ([dcl.fct]) and an *object
> declaration* otherwise.

[[dcl.typedef]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#1):

> Declarations containing the *decl-specifier* `typedef` declare
> identifiers that can be used later for naming fundamental or compound
> types. **The `typedef` specifier shall not be combined in a
> *decl-specifier-seq* with any other kind of specifier except a *defining-type-specifier***, and it shall not be used in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration* ([dcl.fct]) nor in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *function-definition* ([dcl.fct.def]).
> If a `typedef` specifier appears in a declaration without a
> *declarator*, the program is ill-formed.

The code below shows two *typedef declarations*:

```
typedef struct A{ int i; } structA;
```

and

```
typedef const int CI;
```

The first one is fine, as it satisfies the highlighted text in [dcl.typedef]/1, as shown below:

`struct A { int; }` is a [*class-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.pre#nt:class-specifier) which is a [*defining-type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#nt:defining-type-specifier).
`structA` is a [*typedef-name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#nt:typedef-name).

The second `typedef` declaration compiles as we all know, but **it shouldn't**, also according to the text highlighted above, as shown below:

`const` is a *cv-qualifier*, which is a [*type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#nt:type-specifier), which is a [*defining-type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#nt:defining-type-specifier).
`int` is a [*simple-type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#nt:simple-type-specifier), which is a [*type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#nt:type-specifier), which is a [*defining-type-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#nt:defining-type-specifier).

That is, we have two *defining_type_specifiers* in the same `typedef` declaration. I'm not a native English speaker, and I'm assuming that the article 'a' in the expression "except a *defining-type-specifier*" means that only one *defining_type_specifier* is accepted in a `typedef` declaration, according to the alluded paragraph.

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0824a0850a97ea8):

```
typedef struct A{ int i; } structA;
typedef const int CI;

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are exceptions to this rule described below that allows you to write such constructions:

```
typedef const signed short int si;
```

[[dcl.type.general/2]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.general#2)

> As a general rule, at most one `defining-type-specifier` is allowed in the complete `decl-specifier-seq` of a declaration or in a `defining-type-specifier-seq`, and at most one `type-specifier` is allowed in a `type-specifier-seq`. The only exceptions to this rule are the following:
>
> - `const` can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
> - `volatile` can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
> - `signed` or `unsigned` can be combined with `char`, `long`, `short`, or `int`.
> - `short` or `long` can be combined with `int`.
> - `long` can be combined with `double`.
> - `long` can be combined with `long`.